# how to make div of fixed height inside div

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
#displayHeader {
img {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}
 .header-img-inner {
 max-height:100%;
}
}
</style>


<div id="displayHeader" style="height: 83.03px;">
<div class="header-inner">
<div class="row">
<div id="headerCol0" class="col-xs-4 text-center header-img-wrapper">
<div class="header-img-inner">
<img src="test.svg">
<p>TEST</p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="headerCol1" class="col-xs-4 text-center header-img-wrapper">
<div class="header-img-inner">
 <img src="test.svg">
 </div>
        </div>
        <div id="headerCol2" class="col-xs-4 text-center header-img-wrapper">
            <div class="header-img-inner">
                <img src="test.svg">
                <p>tt</p>
            </div>
        </div>

                                        </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div id="displayContent" style="height: 264.8px;">
                                <div class="inner">          
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
 <div>
```

Image and text go out of the div block, why is this happening?

No float left, right used. It's not working with position:relative for parent and position absolute for child, but still not work well.

I only set maximum height for image when I set in on the header-img-inner

Comment: have you tried `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Could you please provide a graphic of what you're attempting to achieve? It's hard to tell from your post. Are you attempting to overlay text over an image? Also, your CSS isn't CSS unless it's LESS/SASS.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **position: inherit;** so as to make the image and whatever you want inside the div to inherit the position. This might help, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
.block {
  text-align: center;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.block:before {
  content: '\200B';
/*   content: '';
  margin-left: -0.25em; */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

.centered {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
 }
```

---

```
<div class="block" style="height: 300px;">

    <div class="centered">
      <h1>Some Text</h1>
        <img src="Untitled-2.jpg" height="150px">
    </div>
 </div>
```

**Please check this link:-https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/**